# BASH: redirect stdin to variable number of subprocesses

Tags: bash, io-redirection

As the title says, I would like to redirect `stdin` to a variable number of output subprocesses.

If I had to redirect to output files I could do something like

```
files=(file_1 file_2 ... file_n)
tee ${files[*]} >/dev/null
```

but with subprocesses (using process substitutions, specifically), doing things like

```
programs=(">(exe_1 args_1)" ... ">(exe_n args_n)")
tee ${programs[@]} >/dev/null
```

will not intepret the `>()` as process substitutions but as literal filenames (for security reasons, I assume); also, the flags withing the substitutions are interpreted as flags of `tee`.

Is it possible to read ONE LINE from `stdin` and redirect it to all these processes (which, again, are variable in number: `n` is unknown)? Have I missed something, somewhere?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to use `eval` to do this (which means a great deal of care is needed to make it secure).

Comment: One option may be to use the `pee` command from the widely-available [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using process substitution, create a bunch of named pipes in a loop, and run each process with its stdin redirected to one of the pipes. Then use `tee` to write to all the pipes.

```
progs=(exe_1 exe_2 ...)
args=(args_1 args2 ...)
pipes=()
arraylenth=${#progs[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ ))
do
    pipe=/tmp/pipe.$$.$i
    mkfifo "$pipe" && pipes+=("$pipe") && "$progs[i]" "$args[i]" < "$pipe" &
done

tee "${pipes[@]" > /dev/null
# Clean up
rm -f "${pipes[@]"
```

This solution has each program run with exactly 1 argument. It's hard to make it more general robustly because bash doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Choosing this as it avoids using `eval`, thank you for your support! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a job for `eval`. Given something like:

```
all_redirections=""

add_redirection() {
  local argv_q
  printf -v argv_q '%q ' "$@"       # generate an eval-safe escaping of "$@"
  all_redirections+=" ${argv_q} "   # append that to all_redirections string
}

to_all_redirections() { eval "tee ${all_redirections}" >/dev/null; }
```

...you can run:

```
add_redirection exe_1 arg_1_a arg_1_b
add_redirection exe_2 arg_2_a
# ...
add_redirection exe_n arg_n
```

...and then, when you have a program whose output is to be copied to the input of those executables:

```
yourprogram | to_all_redirections
```

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code doesn't use `eval` and can handle any number of programs with any number of arguments:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

prog_args=( ::: sed -e 's/^/[1] /'
            ::: sed -e 's/^/[2] /'
            ::: sed -e 's/^/[3] /'  )

exec 3>&1

function tee_to_progs
{
    (( $# < 2 )) && return 1

    local -r startstr=$1
    shift

    local pargs=()
    while [[ $# -gt 0 && $1 != "$startstr" ]]; do
        pargs+=( "$1" )
        shift
    done

    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        # Last program to run.  It can just read stdin and write stdout.
        "${pargs[@]}"
    else
        tee >("${pargs[@]}" >&3) | tee_to_progs "$@"
    fi
}

tee_to_progs "${prog_args[@]}"
```

- The `prog_args` array holds the programs and arguments to be run.  Since Bash doesn't support nested arrays each command is preceded by a marker string to enable the separate programs and arguments to be identified.  I used the string `:::` (because it is used for a similar purpose in GNU Parallel), but *any* string that isn't used as a program name or argument could be used instead.  The code assumes that the first string (whatever it happens to be) in the array is the marker string, so the code doesn't need to be changed if the string is changed.  I tested using `_` instead of `:::`.
- The `sed` commands are just examples.  I used them for testing because the outputs of each program can be easily identified.
- Note that this code only supports running [simple commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Commands).  If you need to run other commands (e.g. ones that use redirections) you will need to use a different approach (probably involving the dreaded `eval`).
- `exec 3>&1` causes file descriptor number 3 to be associated with standard output.  It is used in the code to ensure that output goes to the "real" standard output.
- The `tee_to_progs` function runs the first program in its list of arguments with input duplicated to it with `tee` and pipes the `tee` output to a recursive call of the function that does the same for the second and subsequent programs.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel has `--tee` for this:

```
cat input | parallel --tee --pipe my_program {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Internally it works very much like Barmar's solution, but you get GNU Parallel's output control:

- the output is serialized, so output from two jobs is not mixed
- you can keep the order `--keep-order`
- you can `--tag` each line

and clean up of temporary files is done *before* the job is done, so you do not need to clean up temporary files if the script is killed.

E.g.

```
seq 10000 | parallel --tee --pipe --tag --keep-order grep {} ::: {1..9}
```